# How can I create a "Mark All" checkbox with Vue.js?

Tags: vue.js

I'm learning how to use Vue.js and trying to achieve the following: to basically have a 'Mark All' checkbox where it updates a data property and this update triggers the `onchange` event on other checkboxes. These checkboxes enable or disable their linked fields (kinda like a turn on/turn off for a form i'm building). They also add the field name on a property that will be used to indicate whether the field data will be posted on submission.

Here's a piece of what i have so far.

```js
Vue.component('manual-form', {
  template: `
      <div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-9">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label>Turn all on </label>
      <input type="checkbox" v-on:change="enableAll($event)" class="form-check-label" />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-2">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label>Name</label>
      <input type="checkbox" v-model="checked" v-on:change="turnOnField" name="chkName" class="form-check-label" />
      <input type="text" :disabled="!checked" v-on:input="addData" name="name" placeholder="insert name" class="form-control border-input" />
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="col-md-4">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label>Age</label>
      <input type="checkbox" v-model="checked" v-on:change="turnOnField" name="chkAge" class="form-check-label" />
      <input name="age" :disabled="!checked" v-on:input="addData" type="text" class="form-control border-input" placeholder="enter age" />
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
      `,
  data() {
    return {
      checked: false,
      enabledFields: []
    }

  },
  methods: {
    enableAll: function(event) {
      var check = event.target.checked;

      this.checked = check;
    },
    TurnOnField: function(event) {
      var checkboxName = event.target.name;
      checkboxName = fieldName.substring(3, checkboxName.length);

      var field = document.querySelector("input[name='" + checkboxName + "']");

      var obj = {
        fieldName: field,
        inputData: null
      };

      if (!enabledFields.find(obj.fieldName)) {
        enabledFields.push(obj)
      }

    }
  },
  addData: function() {
    // It will have a underscore debounce to prevent adding every single input
    // insert data on enabledFields
  },
  watch: {
    checked: function(obj) {

    }
  }
});
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.4.4/dist/vue.js"></script>
<manual-form></manual-form>
```

However, programatically changing the checked attribute on checkboxes seems not to fire the `onchange` event. If I click them, they work fine but when using the "Turn All On" checkbox, they don't work. I can achieve what I want withjQuery but I'd like to do it with Vue.js.

I feel I'm missing something but don't know what.

Comment: Think less about the widgets and more about the data that models your state.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't fully understand your code, but you seem to be using a single `checked` property for both fields. What I would do is have a boolean `data` property for each of those fields (so, `chkNameEnabled` and `chkAgeEnabled`), and then have the `enabledFields` data property as a `computed` property which checks the value of those boolean `data` properties and includes the ones that are `true`.

---

Update: After looking at your code in a JSFiddle, it seems you aren't looking at error messages produced by Vue.js in the console.

Here are some problems I found in your code by looking at the error messages:

- The `TurnOnField` function has the first letter capitalized, but in the template code the first letter is lower-case (as it should be).
- You close out the `methods` section before you have the `addData` function.
- You refer to `enabledFields` in the `TurnOnField` function without using
  `this.` before it (`this.enabledFields`).
- You say `checkboxName = fieldName.substring(...)` without having
  defined `fieldName`; it seems like you meant to say `checkboxName =
  checkboxName.substring(...)`.

[Here's](https://jsfiddle.net/50wL7mdz/62006/) a JSFiddle showing "Enable All" functionality as I would do it. You can use the boolean `data` properties to determine "whether the field data will be posted on submission" (as you say in your question).

Comment: Thing is, what i really wanna do is to have one property changed to start the onChange event. And i would like to do it through code, but i think the reactivity of Vue does not allow it.

Comment: But why do you want to do that? Is it so you can have a "enable all" checkbox? If so, that can just be another boolean data property that has a "watch" function that, when the "enable all" property is true, sets the other boolean data properties to all true, and when it's false, sets the other boolean data properties to all be false.

Comment: You answer seems to do it just fine. Thing is, i thought it was possible to trigger the onChange event by changing the checked attribute. Apparently not.